How can I get the "official" WETH which is different from wrapping from Uniswap on Sepolia testnet?
I am trying to make a bid on some NFT assets. I have Sepolia ETH from faucets. I also wrapped the Sepolia ETH into WETH using Uniswap. However, Opensea doesn't seem to recognize that WETH.
This is the address of the WETH contract address 0xfFf9976782d46CC05630D1f6eBAb18b2324d6B14. When I do a google search of "WETH Sepolia contract address", this came up 0x7b79995e5f793A07Bc00c21412e50Ecae098E7f9. Where can I do the swap to get this latter WETH on Sepolia?

Note that there is no official WETH contract - only unofficial ones.

There is no "official" WETH, but here's a method to get WETH for whichever version:
WETH has a deposit (mint) and a withdraw (burn) function. Call deposit on the WETH contract you would like to interact with. The value (amount of ETH) that you send with the call will be the amount of WETH that you will mint and receive. Going the opposite direction you can call withdraw to unwrap your WETH and receive ETH.
